# Область применения очереди сообщений в linux

Tags: linux, c, ipc

Хотелось бы узнать, в каких случаях лучше применять очередь сообщений вместо других средств межпроцессного взаимодействия?

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае когда скорость поступления сообщений в пике выше производительности получателя. В любом случае при асинхронной обработке.